# Toast message cannot appear correctly in React app

Tags: reactjs

**Register.jsx**

```
import toast from 'react-hot-toast'

 const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try{
            const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/auth/register", {
                name, email, password, phone, address, answer
            })
            if(res.data.success) {
                toast(res.data.message,{type: "success", draggable:false})
                navigate("/login")
            } else {
                toast(res.data.message,{type: "error", draggable:false})
            }
        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
            toast("Something Went Wrong",{type: "error", draggable:false})
        }
    }
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import Header from "./Header/Header";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer";
import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const Layout = ({ children, title, description, keywords, author }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta name="description" content={description} />
                <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
                <meta name="author" content={author} />
                <title>{title}</title>
            </Helmet>
            <Header />
            <main style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
                <Toaster />
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

In this React app, I would like to have the toast message appear when the user registered an account. Even I have already imported the toast module it could not work properly. May I ask what I am missing in order to show out the toast message?

Comment: I believe we would need more details, could you show the full code where you handle the account registration?

Answer (score 0):

```
seems your import is not correct , hope below steps can help 

make sure you install below plugins 
npm install react-toastify@9.1.3

update your Layout.jsx file with below content 


import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
import Header from "./Header/Header";
import Footer from "./Footer/Footer";
//import { Toaster } from "react-hot-toast";
//import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const Layout = ({ children, title, description, keywords, author }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <meta name="description" content={description} />
                <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
                <meta name="author" content={author} />
                <title>{title}</title>
            </Helmet>
            <Header />
            <main style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
                <ToastContainer
                    position="top-right"
                    autoClose={2000}
                    hideProgressBar={false}
                    newestOnTop={false}
                    closeOnClick
                    rtl={false}
                    pauseOnFocusLoss
                    draggable={false}
                    pauseOnHover
                    theme="colored"
                />
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```